# sectioning in org-mode to beamer does not work

Tags: org-mode, beamer

I am trying to subdivide my presentation further into section and according to the org docs, setting

#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2

should allow for top-level headlines to be interpreted as sections, whereas not the second level headlines, i.e. ** are defining individual pages. However, in my minimal example below, setting the value from 1 to 2 does not make any difference. What am I missing here?

```
#+TITLE: Abandon all hope

#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [bigger]

#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2

* First page
** Stuff
larifari
** second stuff
larifari
* Second page
** fdjsfsd
larfdfj
** fjs
iiinfdnf
```

Comment: It should work if you use `#+OPTIONS:   H:2` instead of `#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(If I understand well,) the correct way to do this is to replace `#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2` by `H:2` in the global options:

```
#+TITLE: Abandon all hope
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [bigger]
#+options: H:2

* First page
** Stuff
larifari
** second stuff
larifari
* Second page
** fdjsfsd
larfdfj
** fjs
iiinfdnf
```

See for example here: https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-beamer, or directly in [the current Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Frames-and-Blocks-in-Beamer.html):

> Org headlines become Beamer frames when the heading level in Org is equal to org-beamer-frame-level or ‘H’ value in a ‘OPTIONS’ line

Comment: thank you guys!